# Can't Convert SwiftData Model Data to expected argument type NSManagedObject

Tags: swiftui, ios17, swift-data

I have been in the process recently converting my app CoreData code to SwiftData. I have the read and write operations working but ran into a problem with onDelete. I'm guessing that onDelete doesn't like one or more of my parameters in the model TravelEntries class.

> Cannot convert value of type 'TravelEntries' to expected argument type
> 'NSManagedObject'

I searched around the internet but did not find anything on the subject NSManaged Object and SwiftData. I texted out the SwiftData delete and noted that all the data available in deleteEntry was correct, singleOffset had a value of 2 (Int), being the third entry in the list. So what am I missing?

```
@Model class TravelEntries {

    var id: UUID
    var entryDate: Date
    var entryTimeZone: String
    var entryLat: Double
    var entryLong: Double

    var entryCatNum: Int64
    var entryCatName: String
    var entryCode: String
    var entryCurCountry: String
    var entryDsc: String
    var entryPayType: Int64
    var entryMoney: Double
    var entryRate: Double

    var entryLocCity: String
    var entryLocState: String
    var entryLocCountry: String


    init(id: UUID = UUID(), entryDate: Date = Date(), entryTimeZone: String = "", entryLat: Double = 0.0, entryLong: Double = 0.0, entryCatNum: Int64 = 0, entryCatName: String = "", entryCode: String = "", entryCurCountry: String = "", entryDsc: String = "", entryPayType: Int64 = 0, entryMoney: Double = 0.0, entryRate: Double = 0.0, entryLocCity: String = "", entryLocState: String = "", entryLocCountry: String = "") {
        self.id = id
        self.entryDate = entryDate
        self.entryTimeZone = entryTimeZone
        self.entryLat = entryLat
        self.entryLong = entryLong
        self.entryCatNum = entryCatNum
        self.entryCatName = entryCatName
        self.entryCode = entryCode
        self.entryCurCountry = entryCurCountry
        self.entryDsc = entryDsc
        self.entryPayType = entryPayType
        self.entryMoney = entryMoney
        self.entryRate = entryRate
        self.entryLocCity = entryLocCity
        self.entryLocState = entryLocState
        self.entryLocCountry = entryLocCountry
    }
}
```

```
struct HistoryView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Query(sort: \TravelEntries.entryDate) var travelEntries: [TravelEntries]

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { g in

            VStack {
                List {

                    ForEach(travelEntries) { item in
                        showRow(g: g, item: item, entryDate: entryDate)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteEntry)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func deleteEntry(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.forEach { singleOffset in

            // gather entry info necessary to update totals
            let localCur = travelEntries[singleOffset].entryMoney
            let xchRate = travelEntries[singleOffset].entryRate
            let entryCat = Int( travelEntries[singleOffset].entryCatNum)
            let entryDate = travelEntries[singleOffset].entryDate

            viewContext.delete(travelEntries[singleOffset]) // <-- error here

            // ... update system totals
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
```

You need to use

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) var viewContext
```

Make sure you are also using

```
.modelContainer(for: TravelEntries.self)
```

At the top level of the app instead of

```
.environment(\.managedObjectContext, some Context)
```

Apple has a nice article
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/adopting_swiftdata_for_a_core_data_app

`managedObjectContext` is for a CoreData stack not a SwiftData stack.